# How to iterate and return values from list of maps in Dart Language

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a class of Dictionary. Registering a word with a definition.

However, I am stuck where I am trying to input a word and to return a definition. Since I am using a list of maps. I can't really figure out what kind of list methods should I use. I know that I need to iterate a list until it matches the value 'apple' and return the value of 'red'. But how?

```
List<Map<String, String>> wordList = [];
void main() {
  Dictionary.add({'term': 'apple', 'definition': 'red'});
  Dictionary.add({'term': 'banana', 'definition': 'yellow'});

  Dictionary.get('apple'); // THIS SHOULD RETURN 'red'
}

class Dictionary {
  late String term;
  late String definition;

  Dictionary.add(Map<String, String> word) {
    term = word['term']!;
  definition = word['definition']!
    wordList.add(word);
    words.add(term);
  }

  static void get(String word) {
    //FIX ME:
    if()
  }
```

Comment: You should use proper objects for your individual definitions.  That way if you ever want to add another "column" to your "rows", it isn't stuck being another String.

Comment: I know. But I just wanted to figure this out.

Comment: well, you don't want to do a scan of a list of things until you find the one that matches.  you want a Map at the top level, not a List.

Answer (score 1):

Move `wordList` to your dictionary class, it does not make sens to keep it outside and create a method inside the class to return somrthing from the list:

```js
static List<Map<String, String>> wordList = [];
```

Then get rid of this line:

```js
words.add(term);
```

get method:

```js
static String get(String word) {
  for (var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
    if (wordList[i]['term'] == word) {
      return wordList[i]['definition'];
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

then you call it this way:

```js
Dictionary.get('apple')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a Map<String, String> for these use-case.
You could define

```
Map<String, String> wordList = {};
wordList['apple'] = 'red';
wordList['banana'] = 'yellow';
  
// Usage
debugPrint(wordList['apple']);
```

Your class should not include a variable from outside. This approach ... i think it's not good.